# Word Tables import to Access - adding additional character

Tags: vba, ms-access, import, ms-word

I have a VBA script which is importing table data from word to access. Works fine, but in my AccessTable, on every field @ every column, the scripts adds a "Black Dot" at the end of my imported data. Also when the table field was empty.

My data looks like : "31.12.2106" in Word and "31.12.2016*" in Access.

Anyone ideas?

```
For i = 5 To CountTables
 With doc.Tables(i)
         With rst
             .AddNew 'Neuen Eintrag in die Tabelle schreiben
                 ![xx1] = xx
                 ![xx2] = xx1
                 ![xx3] = xx2
                 ![SystemNr] = SystemNr
                 ![xx4] = xx4
                 ![xx5] = xx5
                 ![Scope] = doc.Tables(i).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text
                 ![Action] = doc.Tables(i).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text
                 ![xx6] = doc.Tables(i).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text
                 ![ActionReference] = doc.Tables(i).Cell(7, 1).Range.Text
                 ![RelatedDatabases] = doc.Tables(i).Cell(9, 1).Range.Text
                 ![xx7] = doc.Tables(i).Cell(11, 1).Range.Text
                 ![xx8] = doc.Tables(1).Cell(13, 1).Range.Text
                 ![Result] = doc.Tables(i).Cell(15, 1).Range.Text
                 ![xx9-Nr] = doc.Tables(i).Cell(17, 1).Range.Text
             .Update 'Tabelle updaten
         End With
 End With
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Text` of a Word Cell Range ends with Chr(7), the `BEL` character that serves as cell end character.
Replace all occurences of this:

```
doc.Tables(i).Cell(x, y).Range.Text
```

with this:

```
Replace(doc.Tables(i).Cell(x, y).Range.Text, Chr(7),"")
```

This should suffice.